# Reading client COMPORT from Java applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I need to read client comport accessing my JSP based web application.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>COMPORT</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="blue">
        <h1>ACCESSING COMPORT</h1>
        <jsp:plugin align="middle" height="500" width="500" type="applet" archive="" code="SunCommSerialPort.class" name="clock" codebase="."/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my Java applet code to read COM port.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;

/** @author Venugopal */
public class COMPORT {

    /** @param args the command line arguments */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        COMPORT CM = new COMPORT();
        String StrCommPort = CM.GetSerialPort();
        System.out.println("StrCommPort  " + StrCommPort);
    }

    public String GetSerialPort() {
        String Serialport = "";
        Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                Serialport = Serialport + portId.getName() + "//";
            } else {
                //  ////////////System.out.println(portId.getName());
            }
        }
        if(Serialport !=null && Serialport.length() >0){
            Serialport = Serialport.substring(0, Serialport.length() - 2);
        }
        return Serialport;

    }
}
```

Please tell us what to do.I have kept all necessary files at correct place.
The Java code I have kept here was working after that I have modified extending applet and removing PSVM with `init()` method.

Comment: *"THIS IS MY JAVA APPLET CODE"*  1) Stop YELLING at us. 2) While it is Java code, it is ***not*** an applet.

Comment: *"The Java code I have kept here was working after that I have modified extending applet and removing PSVM with `init()` method."*  Did it not occur to you that the applet code is what we need to see?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of **applet** code. 2) WTF is PSVM? 3) This functionality would require the applet to have full trust.  Why does a web app. need to access COM ports?

Comment: @AndrewThompson PSVM = `public static void main`. (Arguably a worse way of referring to it than just using "`main()`"

Comment: @millimoose  Aha!  I was thinking VM was virtual machine, but PS ..a second 'post script' one?!?  I prefer `main()`. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the applet permission, there are several ways to achieve that. There should be a stacktrace telling you more.

I am somewhat surprised you can sign an applet but don't understand the example, anyway in your jsp applet tag

```
<PARAM NAME="MAYSCRIPT" VALUE="true">
```

make a javascript function eg

```
myfunc(comport){
    //do stuff
}
```

in the applet something like

```
JSObject.getWindow(this).call("myfunc",comport);
```

or

```
JSObject.getWindow(this).eval("myfunc("+comport+")");
```

Also there is DOMService but I never used that, it is more typed but your javascript method will not be there anyway

Comment: I have singed my applet and its working but i want to display in my jp page for that how to pass com port from applet to jsp page can you suggest .

Comment: yes sure you need the jsobject from plugin.jar check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html. You can also use applet method void showDocument(URL url) and pass it as parameter but I prefer the jsobject because the user won't notice

Comment: Thanku for the reply sir ..By reading this example i did not have much idea.If you can elaborate if would be very great for me atleast some example.